# pythonでエクセルの行を移動しながら、データを取得したい。

Tags: python

現在、pythonを用いて自作ウェブアプリのフォームにエクセルに入っているデータを自動入力するツールを開発しています。しかし、エクセルの行が移動されず、同じところばかりコピペされている状態です。それを正しく一段ずつ下に降り、コピペされるように変えたいです。以下、コードです。

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time

import openpyxl


#エクセルファイル、シートの読み込み
file = input("ファイルを入力してください:")
sheet = input("ワークシートを入力してください:")

#ページに遷移済み


def back():
"""入力ページに戻る関数"""
    SKIP_URL ="URL"
    driver.get(SKIP_URL)
    time.sleep(1)

def create_data_list():
"""シートを読み込み、一行ごとのデータリストを作成します。"""
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
    ws = wb[sheet]

    data_list = []
    header_cells = ws[1]

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row):
        row_dic = dict([(k.value, v.value) for k, v in zip(header_cells, row)])
        data_list.append(row_dic)
        return data_list

#ここから指定した回数（ここでは100回）をループで行います。
#入力ページ遷移→データ生成→入力→ページ遷移をループします。
for i in range(100):  
    back()
    data_list = create_data_list()
    time.sleep(1)

    for data in data_list:
"""データリストから４つのデータを取り出します。"""
        v_excel_title = data['title']
        v_excel_lead = data['lead']
        v_excel_author = data['author']
        v_excel_url = data['url'] 

        v_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
        v_c_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
        v_lead = driver.find_element_by_id('id_heading').send_keys(v_excel_lead)
        v_url = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_url').send_keys(v_excel_url)
        v_author = driver.find_element_by_id('id_creator').send_keys(v_excel_author)

    time.sleep(1)

    #保存します。
    save_draft = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.action-save.button-longrunning")
    save_draft.click()
```

以上のコードではセルが移動しないこと以外、正常に作動します。
つまり分けられたデータ（同じデータですが）を100回ループして、入力して保存されます。
あとは次の行、次の行と進むだけです。

ただ、検索してもどう改善すればよいのかわからず、困っています。
ぜひお力をお貸しください。お願いいたします。

Comment: `create_data_list()` 関数ですが、最後の `return data_list` のインデントの高さを間違えています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし、それが問題解決にはなっていないみたいです。

Comment: そうでしょうね、、、私が不思議に思っているのは、100回のループの内部で毎回 `data_list = create_data_list()` を実行していることです。`create_data_list` の関数定義を見る限り、毎回同じ結果になるはずです(`data_list` の中身が常に同じ)。

Comment: たしかに、同じコードばかり見ていると視野が狭くなってしまっていました。これでいけそうなのですが、なぜか毎度保存されません。これもインデントが違いますか？

Comment: ええと、少し確認させていただきたいことがあるのですが、100回ループしているのはデータが100行あるから、ですか？

Comment: そうです。その認識でまちがいありません。

Comment: 回答に書いてみましたので動作確認をしてみて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私:

> 少し確認させていただきたいことがあるのですが、100回ループしているのはデータが100行あるから、ですか？

Kazuhiroさん:

> そうです。その認識でまちがいありません。

そうなりますと、最後のループは以下の様になるのではないでしょうか。

```py
data_list = create_data_list()
for data in data_list:
    back()
    time.sleep(1)

    """データリストから４つのデータを取り出します。"""
    v_excel_title = data['title']
    v_excel_lead = data['lead']
    v_excel_author = data['author']
    v_excel_url = data['url'] 

    v_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
    v_c_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
    v_lead = driver.find_element_by_id('id_heading').send_keys(v_excel_lead)
    v_url = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_url').send_keys(v_excel_url)
    v_author = driver.find_element_by_id('id_creator').send_keys(v_excel_author)

    time.sleep(1)

    #保存します。
    save_draft = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.action-save.button-longrunning")
    save_draft.click()
```